# Basic HTML/CSS: css not displaying for first container

Tags: html, css

I'm playing around with basic divs and testing my code locally and I'm stumped as to why my first div's CSS is not displaying. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as my second div seems to be displaying fine.

I am trying to have my second div centered directly in the middle of my second div, with the first div with a simple colored bg.

```css
div#banner {
  background-color: rgb(52, 72, 94);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
div#bannerbox {
  margin: 0px auto;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="bannerbox">
    testing
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If your question is what I think it is, it may be better to replace "first" and "second" with "outer" and "inner", for better terminology of what you're talking about.

Comment: Well, you're using CSS to target IDs (`#`) and your actual elements use classes

Answer (score 2):

You are targeting id's but in HTML you use classes.

Do CSS like this

```
.banner {
    background-color: rgb(52, 72, 94);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

.bannerbox {
    margin: 0px auto;
    height:50%;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: also a note to perhaps explain to OP that `.thing` references classes and `#thing` references id's, in CSS syntax

Comment: Thank you! I've changed my CSS, but my background color is still not displaying for my banner div.

Comment: @Clark it should be given the code you provided, see example https://jsfiddle.net/kvb5hb6f/4/